# formalize xml input to simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I write a simple function to create xml element with data like :

```
$item->addChild('title', '<![CDATA[<font color="#9353ce">All Content Is Dynamically Loaded</font>]]>');
```

But the data won't output like I want but it contains some html entities :

```
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;font color="#FFFFFF"&gt;
```

I've checked the function html_entity_decode but it seems to convert double quotes and single quotes only :)

Thanks for reading this and I hope someone can help me .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [htmlspecialchars-decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to get them back to the format you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In XML,

```
<title>
  <![CDATA[<font color="#9353ce">All Content Is Dynamically Loaded</font>]]>
</title>
```

is semantically the same as

```
<title>
  &lt;font color="#9353ce"&gt;All Content Is Dynamically Loaded&lt;/font&gt;
</title>
```

So perhaps the following could have the desired output (the second version above)?

```
$item->addChild(
  'title',
  '<font color="#9353ce">All Content Is Dynamically Loaded</font>'
);
```

(unless you have other reasons why you really need to serialize as a CDATA section)

Comment: Yes I have particularly reason to make sure it must be exactly like that :) Thanks for your answer !